# Long twoheadrightarrow

Tags: symbols, amssymb

Is it possible to have a **LONG** twoheadrightarrow?
There exists `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto`, but is there also a long version of the `\twoheadrightarrow`?

Comment: `\xtwoheadrightarrow{}` from package `extpfeil` perhaps?

Comment: And by the way: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

this requires `amssymb` (which loads `amsfonts`), and isn't guaranteed to work with
anything but computer modern:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\longtwoheadrightarrow
     {\relbar\joinrel\twoheadrightarrow}
```

the basic definition is found in `fontmath.ltx` (built into the latex format).

various "other" arrows are found in `amsfonts`, with names assigned in `amssymb`.

these were all created to be compatible with the computer modern arrows, and can
be joined and combined in many different ways.